# What will nodejs http module do when "on data" event listener is not set?

Tags: node.js, http, tcp

```
'use strict';

const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  (async () => {
    await (new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 10000)));
    console.log('recv...');
    req.setEncoding('utf8');
    req.on('data', (chunk) => {
      fs.writeFileSync('test.txt', chunk, { flag: 'a' });
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
      res.end();
    });
  })();
}).listen(23380, '0.0.0.0');
```

What will nodejs http module (or in general http protocol) do when "on data" event listener is not set?

Throw packages away (Will it lose packages)?

Or store packages in memory (Will it eat all my memory)?

Or tell the client "Hey, I don't want your packages. Send me later"?

How does it work?

I will be grateful if you can show some reference (Source code or documentation).

Answer (score 0):

What `http.createServer` actually provides is an EventEmitter [Source](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/#create-the-server). Therefore your question could be simplified into asking on what happens to events that are not been listened to.

For an event, regardless of who listens to that particular event if the condition is met for it to occur, it will. Therefore if **"data"** event is emitted by the EventEmitter provided by http.createServer you cannot stop it by not listning to it. What you're actually doing is just ignoring it.

When you listen to the **data** object what you're actually doing is adding a new Listener to the array of listeners to that particular object ([Source](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_event_newlistener)) using the **req.on** action. So if you have not subscribed to that event it will simply not be delivered to you and that's it. How it will affect the code depends on if the code can do without the event nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

After an afternoon in the reading source code, I think I find the answer to the question.

The http server will receive data at first.

But when data in data pool reach the watermark line, it will **pause** socket, as https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_server.js :366 said and the code is at https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_server.js :636.

Pausing socket means the server will tell the client "Don't send me more data". I found "tcp window full" in Wireshark and I think it is sent by the server because of pause.

Pausing socket also means it will **not make the memory explosion** and it will **not lose the data** neither. (Data is still **stored in client**)

While setting the event listener, the stream will be resumed. Code is at https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_readable.js :826.

The processing continues.